# Obtener campos que no existen en otra tabla, mysql

Tags: sql

Estoy tratando de listar datos simples en una tabla de MYSQL cuyo cierto campo no tenga valores que se encuentren en otra tabla y no me está funcionando:

**En un tabla tengo los dos siguientes campos:**

`idcot`, `nombre`

**En la otra otra tengo los siguientes campos:**

`idcot`, `persona`.

Pues bien quiero listar la información de la primera tabla siempre y cuando los valores de la primera tabla respecto al campo `idcot` no se encuentren tambien en el campo `idcot` de la segunda tabla, mi consulta sería asi:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT idcot FROM cotizaciones 
) AS chido
WHERE idcot not IN
(SELECT idcot FROM facturas)
```

El asunto es que no me está funcionando, se supone que me debe arrojar todos los datos siempre y cuando NO se encuentren en la otra tabla, algo estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto puedes hacerlo con un `LEFT JOIN` solamente cambiando un poco la sentencia `ON` tu consulta deberia de quedar mas o menos de la siguiente forma

```
SELECT *
FROM cotizaciones
LEFT JOIN facturas ON cotizaciones.idcot = facturas.idcot
WHERE facturas.idcot = NULL
```

Recuerda que al final de cuentas los `JOIN` son operaciones de conjuntos, te puedes basar en la siguiente imagen para cuando debas hacer algo similar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias, estás gráficas son muy instructivas